# Script to change the timestamp of files according to filename

Tags: scripting, osx, timestamps

I'm in a macOS environment.

I'd like to change the time stamp on multiple files that has names that starts with this format:

```
XXXXX_DD_MM_YYYY_HH-MM-SS_
```

This is an example of a filename:

```
CALLU_16-10-2018_10-58-26_p123456789012.mp3
```

Creation and modification date should be change to 16/10/2018 at 10:58:26.

I had the following script for filenames of the form `Call@1234567890(1234567890)_20160624205913`.  It extracts date and time from the end of the file name, as a parameter for `touch -t STAMP`:

```
for f in *; do
    t="$(awk '/_.*/ { match($0, /_.*/)
                      print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 7)
                    }'<<<"$f" )"
    touch -t "$t" "$f" 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: I'd like to change the attribute of the file itself. The meta data is necessary to be with date of modify, creation etc. with da information of the file named in that format.

Comment: find . -iname 'XXXX*' | xargs touch

Comment: Try removing the `2>/dev/null` to see a useful error message, possibly including the output of the `awk` step.

Comment: this should work, provided that the `XXXXX` doesn't contain `-` or `_`: `xtouch(){ (set -f; IFS='_-'; f=$1; set -- $f; touch -t "$4$3$2$5$6.$7" "$f") }; xtouch CALLU_16-10-2018_10-58-26_p123456789012.mp3`. I don't have any MacOS to test on, though.

Answer (score 0):

### The old problem

Your old `awk` script was searching for the first `_` in the filename, and then using everything from the next character (`RSTART+1`) to 6 characters before the end (`RLENGTH-7`: +1-7 = -6).

On your input filename, that would produce `20160624`, ie. just the date, without time-of-day.  From the [`touch` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html):

> The option-argument shall be a decimal number of the form:
>
> ```
> [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
> ```
>
> where each two digits represents the following:
>
> ```
> MM
>  The month of the year [01,12].
> DD
>  The day of the month [01,31].
> hh
>  The hour of the day [00,23].
> mm
>  The minute of the hour [00,59].
> CC
>  The first two digits of the year (the century).
> YY
>  The second two digits of the year.
> SS
>  The second of the minute [00,60].
> ```

...which would mean, with only 8 digits, the "20" is interpreted as the month, ie. an invalid date.  But you wouldn't see `touch` reporting an error because of the `2>/dev/null`.

You would have needed to add 4 more characters (to provide `hh` and `mm`), by using eg. `RLENGTH-3`.  But that's only useful on the old filenames.

### The new problem

In your filename `CALLU_16-10-2018_10-58-26_p123456789012.mp3`, the date `16-10-2018` is in little-endian order (DD-MM-CCYY), so your `awk` script will need to swap the components, as well as removing all the separators:

```
awk -F '[-_]' '{print $4$3$2$5$6"."$7}'
```

(If your input filenames contain additional `-` characters before the date, this will need further steps to extract the parts between the `_`s first.)

Test this with your example file:

```
$ echo 'CALLU_16-10-2018_10-58-26_p123456789012.mp3' | awk -F '[-_]' '{print $4$3$2$5$6"."$7}'
201810161058.26
```

So your updated script could look something like:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
    t=$(echo "$f" | awk -F '[-_]' '{print $4$3$2$5$6"."$7}')
    touch -t "$t" "$f"
done
```

Comment: infact if I use your routine, it produce "out of range or illegal time specification: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]"

Comment: @GiancarloPassaglia Sorry, what command did you run to see that error message?  `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]` is the *format*, not the exact argument.